# How do I select a programmed memory scan on the Yaesu FT-897D?

Tags: transceiver, yaesu, equipment-operation

The Yaesu FT-897D has a so-called “Programmable Memory Scan (PMS)” feature, which allows limiting scanning to a user-defined band by creating special paired memory entries which set the upper and lower frequency bounds.

I've used it successfully on the first programmed band (M-P1L to M-P1U), but I can't figure out how to select a different programmed band to scan. I've tried selecting M-P1L before entering PMS mode and it just goes to PMS-1 instead of PMS-2, and none of the controls *in* PMS mode change bands that I've noticed.

[The manual](http://www.yaesu.co.uk/files/FT-897D%20Operating%20Manual.pdf) on page 50 discusses how to enable PMS but not how to change bands. Searching for advice on the web only turned up [this rather annoyed person's workaround](http://www.eham.net/ehamforum/smf/index.php?topic=82545.0) of SKIPping the memories other than the one to use, which can't possibly be how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PMS pairs interact with tuning similarly to the built-in band limits. Use the usual tuning controls (MEM/VFO CH or DIAL) to go past an end — higher than M-PxU or lower than M-PxL — and the transceiver will switch to the next or previous PMS pair.

As far as I've found, this is the *only* way to change between PMS pairs. Pressing the BAND buttons will *not* do so, and will merely disable PMS and change bands normally.

If you leave and re-enter PMS mode the last used PMS pair will be remembered, but the VFO will be reset to the M-PxL frequency.